# Is there an 'insert mesh' brush or addon for blender's sculpting workflow?

Tags: mesh, workflow, sculpting

I've been spending more time sculpting in Blender. I would love to see a brush like Zbrush's insert mesh brush.
The insert mesh in Zbrush draws a primitive of your choosing right on the mesh in the direction of the normal. As you drag horizontally or vertically while holding down the stylus, the primitive's size/diameter change as needed.

Is there anything out there like this? It seems like a simple function, yet no addons exist that come near to it.

It is extremely useful for character modeling. I would love to know if there's an addon that does this.

Comment: See if this works for you: MifthTools Draw Clone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=repgVyh7PnY

Comment: That's the closest I've seen to the Zbrush tool, thanks :) The Zbrush version has extra control, but I can't complain, this works pretty well.